# Can I extend a type at runtime through extension methods

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that receives objects inheriting an interface IThing say, and converts them to a new object ConvertedThing. The problem is that the conversion process is very different depending on the concrete type of the IThing but I do not want to cast to the underlying type as this is not unit testable. Ideally I would write extension methods for each of the concrete types to convert them then extend the interface somehow to call this extension method but this is not possible as the extension methods will need to have the signature of IThing, I cannot access extension methods on the concrete type through the interface. I cannot just program the conversion on the IThing iterface because my conversion is just one of the possible conversions that IThings could go through and the designers don't want IThing to have any knowledge of the conversion. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IThing thing = new ConcreteThing();
        IConvertibleThing convertibleThing = new ConvertibleThing(thing);
        ConvertedThing convertedThing = convertibleThing.Convert();
    }

    public interface IThing
    {

    }

    public interface IConvertibleThing
    {
        ConvertedThing Convert();
    }

    public class ConvertibleThing : IConvertibleThing
    {
        public IThing Thing { get; set; }
        public ConvertibleThing(IThing thing)
        {
            Thing = thing;
        }
        public ConvertedThing Convert()
        {
            return Thing.Convert();
        }
    }

    public class ConcreteThing : IThing
    {
    }
}

public static class ThingConverters
{
    public static ConvertedThing Convert(this IThing thing)
    {
        // I don't want this ever to be called
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public static ConvertedThing Convert(this ConcreteThing thing)
    {
        //I always want this to be called
        // DO Conversion
        return new ConvertedThing();
    }
}

public class ConvertedThing
{
}
```

Comment: why is an extension-method unit-testable, while a cast is not? Could you please show some sample class-structure that shows what you want to achieve? It´s pretty hard to follow your instructions.

Comment: Remember that extension methods are just syntactic sugar. They get called like any other method under the covers.

Comment: Hi I've added some code.

Comment: The problem is that the exception always gets thrown but I want to return a converted thing via the extension method. How can i get the compiler to look at the concrete implementation when selecting an extension method same as it would an ordinary method?

Comment: You don't. Only virtual methods work like that, not extension methods. (Interface methods are implicitly virtual.) Extension methods are strictly a compile-time thing.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. Is there a way to get the behaviour I want using something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension methods are static, so are not contained in the virtual method lookup table. If you want to use them for polymorphism, you'll have to create your own fake vmt, which can be as simple as a dictionary.

```
public interface IThing
{
}

public interface IConvertibleThing
{
    IConvertedThing Convert();
}
public interface IConvertedThing
{
}

public class ConvertibleThing : IConvertibleThing
{
    public IThing Thing { get; set; }
    public ConvertibleThing(IThing thing)
    {
        Thing = thing;
    }
    public IConvertedThing Convert()
    {
        return Thing.Convert();
    }
}

public class ConcreteThing : IThing
{
}

public class ConvertedThing : IConvertedThing
{
}

public static class ConversionExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<Type,Func<IThing,IConvertedThing>> vmt = new Dictionary<Type,Func<IThing,IConvertedThing>>();

    public static void RegisterConverter(this Type type, Func<IThing,IConvertedThing> func)
    {
        vmt.Add(type,func);
    }

    public static IConvertedThing Convert(this IThing source)
    {
        return vmt[source.GetType()](source);
    }
}



public class Program
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        //Initialization
        typeof(ConcreteThing).RegisterConverter( x => new ConvertedThing() );

        //Body of program
        IThing thing = new ConcreteThing();
        IConvertibleThing convertibleThing = new ConvertibleThing(thing);
        IConvertedThing convertedThing = convertibleThing.Convert();
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xLR6G8)

Note: I'm not saying this is a good idea, this is just the only way to have "virtual" methods without actually adding virtual methods to the class itself.